# Resize Firefox 3.6's 'Back' button to make it larger

Tags: ubuntu, firefox-3.6

I'm using `Firefox 3.6` on Ubuntu and I believe the back button's default was small (I.e., the same size as the forward button).

I know there are many fixes to make it small, however, I would like to make it big like the usual Firefox.

i.e.,

[image: Big vs. Small Back Button]

I would like to have the first image.

EDIT: the "Use Small Icons" box under Toolbar > Customize is toggled off. Never played with it before. The Back button was *never* large.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Starting with Firefox 3, different UIs are used on different operating systems. The Linux version uses a traditional GTK2 toolbar where all buttons are of the same size and separate from each other.

[image: beta screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

Do the **reverse** of this (i.e. uncheck the box):

> If you're not a fan of Firefox 3's large back button, you don't have to wrangle with CSS or themes to adjust its size. Simply right-click on Firefox's toolbar, and choose Customize. In the dialog box, select "Use small icons"—and voila! Your back button will be the same size as reload.

From: [Shrink Firefox 3’s Supersized Back Button](http://lifehacker.com/392452/shrink-firefox-3s-supersized-back-button)

Comment: sorry I'll edit the question -- this is unchecked. I've never played with any of the toolbar settings before.